# Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease 403 Forbidden

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-center, update-manager

This is not a duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

When I run `sudo apt update` I got error:

```
Hit:1 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
...
Hit:15 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu focal InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I got a `403 Forbidden`.

I found this [How can I fix a 403 Forbidden Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018341/how-can-i-fix-a-403-forbidden-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-list) which I tried

```shell
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:morphis/anbox-support
```

But I got this error:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~morphis/ubuntu/anbox-support'.
The user named '~morphis' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/anbox-support'
Please choose from the following available PPAs:
 * 'ffmpeg':  FFMpeg backport
 * 'intel-media':  Intel Media Driver Backport
 * 'mesa':  Mesa patches
 * 'scrcpy':  scrcpy
 * 'staging':  Package staging area
 * 'touch-staging':  Touch Staging
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: It could be that the PPA could be incompatible with your Ubuntu Release. What is the Ubuntu release?

Comment: `The user named '~morphis' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/anbox-support'` seems clear. What leads you to believe that such a PPA exists?

Comment: Anbox is abandoned, that's why there's nothing in the PPA.

Comment: @Rishon_JR my ubuntu release is `20.04`

Comment: @user535733 when I execute `sudo apt update` you can see in log that `apt` try to reach `http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu` which is forbidden now. But it used to work. How can I fix that so I can execute `sudo apt update` without having an error ?

Comment: @popey I anderstand that but how can I fix that so I can `sudo apt update` without having an error ?

Comment: You must delete the apt source that no longer exists.

Comment: @user535733 I tried to do it with `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:morphis/anbox-suppor` but I got an error

Comment: There's probably a file called `morphis-ppa.list` or similar in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` which you can just remove, and then `apt update` and all will be good again.

Answer (score 1):

It's right there in your output:

```
The user named '~morphis' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/anbox-support'
```

You are getting a 403 error instead of a 404 error merely due to the Launchpad server settings.

You fix both 403 and 404 problems exactly the same way: By deleting the non-existent apt source.

How to do so is thoroughly explained at [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Answer (score 0):

As `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:morphis/anbox-support` didn't work I listed all sources with `ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 21 10:57 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Mar 21 14:00 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  112 Mar 21 10:57 docker.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  112 Mar 21 10:57 docker.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Mar 21 10:57 google-chrome.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Mar 21 10:57 google-chrome.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  142 Mar 21 10:57 graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  142 Mar 21 10:57 graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  144 Mar 21 10:57 morphis-ubuntu-anbox-support-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  144 Mar 21 10:57 morphis-ubuntu-anbox-support-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   89 Mar 21 10:57 mssql-release.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   89 Mar 21 10:57 mssql-release.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  122 Mar 21 10:57 ondrej-ubuntu-php-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  122 Mar 21 10:57 ondrej-ubuntu-php-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   50 Mar 21 10:57 symfony-cli.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   50 Mar 21 10:57 symfony-cli.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1255 Mar 21 10:57 teamviewer.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1255 Mar 21 10:57 teamviewer.list.save
```

and I manually deleted `morphis-ubuntu-anbox-support-focal.list` and `morphis-ubuntu-anbox-support-focal.list.save`:

```
sudo rm morphis-ubuntu-anbox-support-focal.list
sudo rm morphis-ubuntu-anbox-support-focal.list.save
```

Now everything works fine